# Implications of Derived class having a different ABI, than Base class?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, abi, vtable

While debugging with gdb, printing the vtable yields something like the following:

```
(gdb) info vtbl *object
vtable for 'my_namespace_B::MyDerivedObject' @ 0x555555690bf0 (subobject @ 0x5555556ab710):
[0]: 0x55555559ff42 <my_namespace_A::MyBaseObject::function1[abi:cxx11]() const>
[1]: 0x5555555a016c <my_namespace_A::MyBaseObject::function2[abi:cxx11]() const>
[2]: 0x5555555a030a <my_namespace_A::MyBaseObject::function3() const>
[5]: 0x5555555a47f8 <my_namespace_B::MyDerivedObject::~MyDerivedObject()>
[6]: 0x5555555a4846 <my_namespace_B::MyDerivedObject::~MyDerivedObject()>
[7]: 0x5555555a0a80 <my_namespace_B::MyDerivedObject::fun1(bool)>
```

What does the `[abi:cxx11]` part mean?
I understand that this should mean that that part of the code was compiled using cxx11 features.

- is this understanding even correct?
- What implications might this have?
- Could this be the reason why calling the virtual function `fun1` from within `BaseObject::nonVirtualMemberFunction` yields undefined behavior?

Comment: How might your base class have a different ABI? Did you compile it separately from the derived?

Comment: They were in different cmake targets, but in the same repository, i am not sure exactly why

Comment: Do these functions return `std::string` or something dependent/related to it? That is the most likely reason for a `cxx11` abi tag to be necessary. A function that doesn't return something that had its ABI changed with C++11 wouldn't need a tag. I don't think there is anything intrinsically wrong with the output you are showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [`abi_tag`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html#C_002b_002b-Attributes) attribute, either applied directly to your function or the return type is tagged.

Most likely your functions just return `std::string`, which libstdc++ tags with `abi_tag("cxx11")` so that code compiled with the old C++03 copy-on-write strings doesn't link to modern code and silently break.

There are no "visible" differences, just that if you compiled something with the old string ABI it wouldn't link. It should work the same as any other virtual function.